# jQuery: Selecting elements that don't have a specific descendant element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

How would I select all table elements that do not have any descendant td elements using jQuery 1.3.2?

Answer (score 6):

You could try:

```
$("table:not(:has(tbody > tr > td))").doStuff();
```

Working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
  $("table:not(:has(tbody > tr > td))").css("background", "yellow");
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
td, th { border: 1px solid black; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
  <td>First table</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>Second table</th>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [CSS `:not()` selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not#selector).

```
table *:not(td)
```

Should do it.

Edit: bah, misread what you wanted.

Comment: On the right track, but `table`s generally will *never* have immediate children that are `td`s, so this won't work as written.

Comment: Yeah, ninja stealth edit. I think he's looking for the tables themselves rather than the tr/td/th I thought he was looking for.

Comment: Yup, I was looking for the tables themselves.