# How to select elements which do not have a specific child element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a JQuery selector to select all elements which do **not** have certain child element as a direct child? For example:

```
<p>
    text in paragraph
</p>
<p>
    <div>text in div</div>
</p>
```

I want to select only `<p>`s like the first one (without a `<div>` child). *Is this possible?*

Further information: Actually I'm trying to insert a `<div>` into all those `<p>` that do not have one by an expression like this:

```
$('p').wrapInner('<div />')
```

But this would add an additional `<div>` to the second `<p>`.

Comment: Granted jQuery can stuff a `<div>` into a `<p>` for some bizarre reason (I just tested it, and wha–?!), but you should probably use a better example, like `<div>` for parents and `<p>` for children instead, because it's not valid HTML to have a `<div>` inside a `<p>`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: Selecting elements that don't have a specific descendant element](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1602098/jquery-selecting-elements-that-dont-have-a-specific-descendant-element)

Comment: @BoldClock: Well, I didn't know this. The real structure is much more complicated and has no `<div>` inside a `<p>`. I tried to simplify it.

Comment: @Stephan then its even worse ...

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You could try:

```
$("p:not(:has(>div))")
```

Comment: Thank you! This one even meets the direct child requirement!

Comment: Nice solution. Helped to select lowest-level li in a nested list: $("li:not(:has(li))")

Comment: Unfortunately, `:has` is not supported by native `document.querySelector` :( .

Answer (score 15):

You can combine the [`:has()`<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector with the [`not` function<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not/) to acheive this:

```
$("p").not(":has(div)").wrapInner("<div/>");
```

Alternatively, you can use a single selector by using the [`:not()`<sup>[docs]</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector:

```
$("p:not(:has(div))").wrapInner("<div/>");
```

You can use either interchangeably, but IIRC, the first is faster.

[See it in action on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zknFw/1/).

Note that `div` is a block-level element and `p` is not. That means it is not valid HTML to have a `div` nested in a `p`.

Comment: @BoltClock, I know, I think using the function is faster. I may be wrong, though

Answer (score 1):

structural elements inside text elements look very unclean to me but if you insist ;)

```
$('p').not(":has(div)").wrapInner("<div/>");
```

here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/NTpES/3/

Comment: But `:has` selects when there is a `<div>` somewhere in the child hierarchy. I want to check for **direct childs** only.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("p").filter("not(:has(div))").wrapInner("<div/>");
```

Comment: i think it has to be :not(ect...) but you could directly use .not() ;)

Comment: There is spell mistake. Try using `$("p").filter(...);` instead of `$("p").fitler(...);`.

Answer (score -2):

This seems to work: `$('p:not("p div")')`

Comment: No, it doesn't. First off, `:not()` as a selector doesn't use quotes. Second, *every* `p` is not a `p div` (because `p` is not `div`).

Comment: How odd -- it works when I test it in a standalone page, but not in a jsFiddle. To tell the truth, I didn't think it would work before I tried it.