# How can I select an element which does not contain a certain child element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="test">
 <div class="example"></div>
</div>

<div class="test">
</div>
```

How can I apply jQuery to an element with the class `test` only if it doesn't contain a child element with the class `example`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to select elements which do not have a specific child element with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258606/how-to-select-elements-which-do-not-have-a-specific-child-element-with-jquery)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

```
$('.test:not(:has(.example))')
```

-or-

```
$('.test').not(':has(.example)')
```

Answer (score 5):

Possibly

```
$('.test').filter(function() { return !$(this).children('.example').length; });
```

This filters out any elements that have any child that matches `.example`. If you want to filter based on descendants (not just children) that you can substitute `.find` for `.children`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$(':not(.test:has(.example))').css('color', 'red');​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9fkz7y1g/

Comment: Your JSFiddle doesn't contain the code in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery `contains()`:

```
jQuery.contains(document.documentElement, document.body); // true
jQuery.contains(document.body, document.documentElement); // false
```

Answer (score 2):

This problem seems ready-made for the `filter` function where you find all the `.test` objects and then when filtering retain only the ones that don't have `.example` in them:

```
$(".test").filter(function() {
    return($(this).find(".example").length == 0);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the method [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) with ".example" and test if it is empty

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('.test').each(function() {
    if(!$(this).children().hasClass("example")){
       //your code
    }
});
```

Maybe like this? I haven't tested this...

Answer (score -1):

```
if (!$('#yourDiv').children().hasClass("className")) {
    //i.e. yourDivID' has no any children whose class name =>'className'
}
```