# add a class to a div checking for children

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to add a class to a div when certain children don't exist which will move the header down. I'm aware that this is a duplicate as I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10168248/if-parent-element-does-not-contain-certain-child-element-jquery).

The top voted answer does not work - It's applying the class to both headers and I don't know why.

See my code below:

```js
var linkCheck = $('.navigation').not(':has(.nav-link )');
if (linkCheck) {
  $(".main-header").addClass("no-links-header");
}
```

```css
.no-links-header {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-header">
<h2>The Main Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
</div>


<div class="main-header">
<h2>Move this Header down</h2>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: *"it's applying the class to both headers and I don't know why."* - Because you have two elements with the class `main-header`?

Comment: well it's adding the class to both headers because `$(".main-header")` selects ALL elements with class `main-header` in `$(".main-header").addClass("no-links-header");`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to apply the class only to the preceding `.main-header`. Your current code will apply the class to *all* `.main-header` elements.

[.prev()](https://api.jquery.com/prev/) will select the preceding element. Which in your case will be the `.main-header` element.

```js
// A collection of .navigation elements that do not have children
let navs = $('.navigation').not(':has(.nav-link )');
 
// Loop through your collection
navs.each(function() {
  
  // Find the preceding .main-header element and add the class
  $(this).prev().addClass('no-links-header');
})
```

```css
.no-links-header {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-header">
<h2>The Main Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
</div>


<div class="main-header">
<h2>Move this Header down</h2>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would try this (not tested):

```
var linkCheck = $('.navigation').not(':has(.nav-link )');

$(linkCheck).addClass("no-links-header");
```

This way, the class should only be added to the element matching the selector of `linkCheck`.

Comment: This adds the class to the wrong element (the `.navigation` not the `.main-header`). Also note that you can format your code using the '{ }' icon when posting an answer.

Comment: You are right, I misread the question. Is it possible to use code blocks when answering on a smartphone too? Because the only option I see is adding an image to my answer.

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed that (I'm sure you used to be able to). You can get around this by adding 4 spaces before each line of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using `next` to target the header that is closest to the navigation without links...

```js
$(".navigation").each(function(){
  if($(this).children(".nav-link").length > -1){
    $(this).next(".main-header").addClass("no-links-header");
  }
})
```

```css
.no-links-header {
  color: red;
  margin-bottom: -80px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="main-header">
<h2>The Main Header</h2>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#">A Link</a>
</div>


<div class="main-header">
<h2>Move this Header down</h2>
</div>

<div class="navigation">
</div>
```