# Remove all element that does not have specific descendandt element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

So i have the following markup:

```
<div class="festi-cart-products-content">
    <table class="festi-cart-list">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
                <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
                </td>
                <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
                    <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
                    <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount"></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

there are multiple tr elements, but only some of them have the innermost span with "woocommerce-Price-amount" class. The other have nothing after the "festi-cart-product-price" classed span.

I'm trying to remove all the tr elements that does NOT have the "woocommerce-Price-amount" span inside it using jQuery.

```
jQuery( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {

    jQuery(".festi-cart-product-price:not(:has(>span))").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).parent('tr.festi-cart.item').hide();
    });

});
```

I've been trying to use the :not selector, but it doesnt seem to produce anything. I'm really not sure where it goes wrong.

Can any of you spot where my code is going wrong, or if it's a completely hopeless approach to a simple solution?

Comment: Typo, the class on the `tr` is `festi-cart-item`, not `festi-cart.item`

Comment: `$('.festi-cart-product-price:not(:has(.woocommerce-Price-amount))').closest('.festi-cart-item').hide();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$('.btn').click(function(){
$('.festi-cart-item').each(function(){
var price = $(this).find('.festi-cart-product-price').children().hasClass('woocommerce-Price-amount');
  if(!price)
    $(this).hide();
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="festi-cart-products-content">
    <table class="festi-cart-list">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
                <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
                </td>
                <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
                    <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
                    <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount"></span>
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>
  <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
                <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
                </td>
                <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
                    <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
                    <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                       
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>    
          <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
                <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
                </td>
                <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
                    <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
                    <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                       
                    </span>
                </td>
            </tr>    
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<button class="btn">remove</button>
```

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly on first try. just changed the click handler to document on ajaxComplete :).

Answer (score 3):

Use `.filter` function to match elements with specific requirements.

Use `$('tr').find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').length > 0` to check if element exists in `tr`.

Than simply do `.hide()` (or `.remove()`) to filtered elements.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var hasWoo = $('.festi-cart-list tr').filter(function() {
    return $(this).find('.woocommerce-Price-amount').length !== 0;
  });

  hasWoo.hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="festi-cart-products-content">
  <table class="festi-cart-list">
    <tbody>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a>
          <br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">WOO</span>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a>
          <br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                        <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">WOO</span>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img">
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a>
          <br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
                      EMPTY
                    </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, good insight on the filtering feature. I needed to target all non woocommerce class elements, so this was kind of reversed but still a nice solution. Might try to flip it around and use it later on but for now i used one of the others. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `.closest()` method of jquery instead of `.parent()` method.

Comment: Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 1):

How about this.

```
$("tr:not(:has(>.woocommerce-Price-amount))").hide()
```

Not tested.

Comes from this question: [How to select elements which do not have a specific child element with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258606/how-to-select-elements-which-do-not-have-a-specific-child-element-with-jquery) which is worth a read on this type of 'descendant without feature' question.

Comment: Never really could get the :not feature to work so I ended up with one of the other answers. Thanks for the input anyways!

Answer (score 1):

You're so close, **your selector is valid** and select the `festi-cart-product-price` that have no `span`'s :

```
$(".festi-cart-product-price:not(:has('>span'))")
```

You've just to go up to the parents `tr` using `closest()` then hide them :

```
selector.closest('tr').hide();
```

Check [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/jnwrc5ay/220/) using `setTimeout()` to see the effect .

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  var selector = $(".festi-cart-product-price:not(:has('>span'))");

  selector.closest('tr').hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="festi-cart-products-content">
  <table class="festi-cart-list" border=1>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img"> IMAGE 1
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">p1</span>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img"> IMAGE 2
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img"> IMAGE 3
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="festi-cart-item ">
        <td class="festi-cart-product-img"> IMAGE 4
        </td>
        <td class="festi-cart-product-title">
          <a class="festi-cart-title" href="">product name</a><br>
          <span class="festi-cart-product-price">
            <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">p4</span>
          </span>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and troubleshooting. Ended up using another answer but thanks for the input!