# JQuery select all selects without options

Tags: jquery, select

Using JQuery how can I select all `<select>` items which do not have any `<option>` children.

I tried `$(".MySelectsClass).not("option")` which didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select elements which do not have a specific child element with JQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7258606/how-to-select-elements-which-do-not-have-a-specific-child-element-with-jquery)

Comment: Could you add a snippet of your "*[mcve]*" HTML, so we can see what your no-option `<select>` elements look like?

Comment: @DavidThomas safe to assume `<select></select>` ?  `<select>` items which have no `<option>` children.

Comment: @freedom: possibly, but there could also be white-space or `<optgroup>` elements included, which affects the choice of selectors. For example: `select:empty` would be the simplest of selectors, but if there's white-space, or any descendant, it won't work. Which is why we shouldn't assume, or make guesses based on minimal information.

Comment: @DavidThomas you are correct, especially regard to `<optgroup>`.  The dodgy edit by Milind has confused the question - it was originally explicitly *"which have no <option> children"*, but now is *"are empty"*, which as you point out, are not the same thing.

Comment: I've restored the question to be explicitly without options (rather than "empty").

Answer (score 1):

You can use `:not` with `:has` selector:

```
$(".MySelectsClass:not(:has(option)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:empty` selector:

```js
$('.MySelectsClass:empty').addClass('foo');
```

```css
.foo {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="MySelectsClass"></select>
<select class="MySelectsClass">
  <option>Not empty!</option>
</select>
<select class="MySelectsClass"></select>
```

Comment: This method would be more performant compared to using the not and the has right?

Comment: I'm not sure on the performance, you can test it with http://jsperf.com if you'd like. Personally I prefer it due to brevity, and being clearer in its intent

Comment: @nauti your question did not ask about performance.  Generally, you want clarify over performance unless you have some niche case where you're trying to do something 1000s times a second, in which case you probably want to be looking at doing it a different way anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) to apply any arbitrary filter, eg in this case:

```js
console.log($("select").length);

var emptyselects = $("select").filter(function(i) {
        return $(this).find("option").length === 0;
    });
console.log(emptyselects.length);
console.log(emptyselects.attr("id"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="s1">
</select>
<select id="s2">
<option>a</option>
</select>
```